# NaN Issue - Why does identical code returns diffrent results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ascii, nan, scramble

I'm working on a script to match scrambled words to their unscrambled counterpart, and I'm running into a weird NaN problem. I have inserted comments below to guide you further in understand my problem in hopes that you can give me an explanation as to why this problem is occurring. Thank you for your time and help.

NOTE: Two chunks of code that are exactly the same (but with different variable names) act differently. The latter works, but the former does not.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="words">
    <input type="hidden" value="html:),121212,21122112,asdfjkl;,hal9000,1234qwer,1q2w3e,test123,gambit,sports,hello!,willie,hashtags,oneway,whoknows,whyowhy,youwho,theone,sweet!,wo0Oot">
  </form>

  <br>
  <li>leho!l</li>
  <li>lilwie</li>
  <li>thahsags</li>
  <li>yaneow</li>
  <li>kwosonhw</li>
  <li>ohhywwy</li>
  <li>oyuwoh</li>
  <li>otheen</li>
  <li>e!stwe</li>
  <li>wtoO0o</li>


  <script>
    var words, scram, wordVals, scramVals, sum, i, I;

    // Turn word list into an array.
    words = [];
    var words = document.getElementById("words").elements[0].value.split(",");

    // Turn scrambled word list into an array.
    scram = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      scram.push(document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerHTML);
    };

    // Next I iterate through each letter of each word (for the unscrambled words)
    // and convert those letters into ASCII values - adding those together
    // to get the total ASCII value of each word.

    wordVals = [];
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      for (I = 0; I < words[i].length; I++) {
        sum += words[i].charCodeAt(I);
        // console.log(sum)

        // Using console.log(sum), you see that the first 6 iterations return NaN.
        // Each iteration (ASCII Value) for the first word in this loop
        // words[0].charCodeAt(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), all returned NaN.
        // But each word after the first iteration calculates the ASCII values
        // like it's supposed to.
      };
      wordVals.push(parseInt(sum));
      sum = 0;
      console.log("Word[" + i + "]: " + words[i] + " - Value: " + wordVals[i]);
    };

    // typeof WordVals[0] = number
    console.log("typeof wordVals[0]?: " + typeof(wordVals[0]));
    // isInteger = false
    console.log("isInteger wordVals[0]?: " + Number.isInteger(wordVals[0]));

    // Here I am iterating through each letter of each word (for the scrambled words)
    // and converting those letters into ASCII values - adding those values together
    // to get the total ASCII value of each word.
    // **This loop uses the same exact code as the one above (but with different variables)
    // and it works correctly. Why is this?

    scramVals = [];
    for (i = 0; i < scram.length; i++) {
      for (I = 0; I < scram[i].length; I++) {
        sum += scram[i].charCodeAt(I);
      };
      scramVals.push(sum);
      sum = 0;
      console.log("Scram Word[" + i + "]: " + scram[i] + " - Value: " + scramVals[i]);
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**OUTPUT:**

- Word[0]: html:) - Value: NaN
- Word[1]: 121212 - Value: 297
  ...rest of list omitted...
- typeof wordVals[0]?: number
- isInteger wordVals[0]?: false
- Scram Word[0]: leho!l - Value: 565
- Scram Word[1]: lilwie - Value: 646
  ...rest of list omitted...

I have tried using a different starting word in my word list but get the same NaN result.

I don't understand why the first block of code doesn't work when it is practically identical to the second block of code that does work!

Why am I getting a NaN on the ASCII values of each letter of the first word?

I'm a beginner, and realize that this is not the proper way to go about finding word matches. Regular Expressions is probably what I will try to end up using, but I need to figure this out so I can progress in the way that I learn.

Thank you. I use this site all the time because I love the no nonsense approach most of you take in addressing user requests. There are a lot of really smart people here donating their time and intelligence, and I really appreciate it.

I am also open to any tips you can give me to improve this code.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `undefined + Number` is `NaN`. Initially, the `sum` variable is `undefined`. that is why the first value in the `wordVals` array is `NaN`.

Just set `sum` to `0` and it should work as expected, ex:

```
var words, scram, wordVals, scramVals, sum = 0, i, I;
```

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! haha. Thank you. That was driving me nutz!

Comment: @aConvolutedConscious I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For the first iteration you adding a number with undefined( ie sum). So it'l become NaN. make sum = 0; at the beginning